# Select second submit button in JS

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, form-submit, testcafe

I want to use TestCafe to click on a submit button in a form. Here is what the button looks like:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-cart pull-left">
<span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">
     <i class="fa fa-shopping-basket"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;
</span>
     Add To Cart
</button>
```

This button is inside a form:

```
<form name="product1" action="domain.tld/product" method="post" role="form">
</form>
```

In my test I want to add the product to the cart:

```
test('add it', async t =>{
     await t
          .click(Selector('button[type="submit"]'))
});
```

The problem is, that in the nabber is another button with the type submit. How can I use this specific button to add my product to the cart?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a more specific selector to execute an action with this button. For example, if this button has a class that another submit button doesn't have, use it to make a more selective selector.

Let's consider an example. Another submit button doesn't have the `pull-left` class. Use the following selectors `Selector('button[type="submit"].pull-left')` or `Selector('.btn.pull-left')`.

If there is no difference between these buttons, you can use the Selector's method `nth(index)`: `Selector('button[type="submit"]').nth(1)`. See more in [our documentation](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/selecting-page-elements/selectors.html#nth).

Answer (score 2):

Submit the second form :

```
$('form').eq(1).submit();
```

You don't need to find the submit button and trigger a click on that. Instead, you can just call .submit() on the form itself.

Comment: It would be to easy to do that. I need to work with the existing code and I am not allowed to change it, so I need to find another solution :)

Comment: you want to get second button from first form ? 
or 
first button from second form ?

Comment: I need to get the first button from the second form (have a look at the form markup in my question)